# Put code into Javascript file?

Tags: javascript

How do I put this into a javascript file that is an additional file to the html page.

I want to convert this piece of code into full javascript, not html assisted.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {          
    $(document).ready(function(){                    
        $(window).scroll(function(){                          
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
                $('#mySidenav').fadeIn(200);
            } else {
                $('#mySidenav').fadeOut(200);
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "full javascript"?

Comment: just copy the contents inside the `<script>` tag and copy in the js file

Comment: `<script src="your_script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: I want to put that code into a java script file, not be implemented into the html page. It doesnt work for me.

Comment: `not to be implemented into the html page` almost sound like you're saying you want the javascript in a file to run on the page without the page invoking it.  Not possible. You either need to have it in the html like you do, or call it in the `<head>` or elsewhere like @maljukan showed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a js file in the same directory as your html file. Call it "main.js". Add to main.js:

```
(function($) {          
    $(document).ready(function(){                    
        $(window).scroll(function(){                          
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
                $('#mySidenav').fadeIn(200);
            } else {
                $('#mySidenav').fadeOut(200);
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

In your html file put:

```
<script src="main.js" type="text/javascript">
```